# MenuItem does not display when adding too many MenuFlyoutItems (.Net Winui3 App)

Tags: .net, winui-3

[image: Issue Gif]

I've got a MenuItem filled with MenuFlyoutItems. I'm doing it via C# but the same issue occurs if I manually add MenuFlyoutItems in the XAML code.

If the number of item's height combines to make a menulist that would be larger than the app's window, then the list is empty. If I make the window larger after attempting to use the menu, the list will draw properly and have a scrollable list as expected.

C#

```
        foreach (string c in CollectionNames)
        {
            MenuFlyoutItem item = new MenuFlyoutItem();
            item.Name = c;
            item.Text = c;
            item.Click += CollectionNameMenuClick;
            CollectionMenu.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

XAML

```
 <Grid Background="#171111">
        <StackPanel>
            <MenuBar x:Name="MenuBar">
                <MenuBarItem Title="File" x:Name="FileMenu">
                    <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="SetImagePathItem" Text="Set Image Path" Click="OnSetImagePathClickedAsync"/>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="ShowOutputPathItem" Text="Open Output Folder" Click="OnShowOutputFolderClicked"/>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="ExitItem" Text="Exit" Click="OnExitClicked"/>
                </MenuBarItem>

               
                <MenuBarItem x:Name="CollectionMenu" Title="Collection" Tapped="CollectionMenu_Tapped">
                </MenuBarItem>
            </MenuBar>
        </StackPanel>
        
        <Grid Margin="15">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Spacing="15">
                <TextBlock x:Name="showingCollectionText" Text="Showing Collection: None" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="pathText" Text="Image Path: None" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>



        </Grid>


    </Grid>
```

This feels like a bug in Winui3, but I thought I'd check here to see if anyone can think of a workaround. I expect it to just work as it has in .Net Maui.

Comment: According to your code, I couldn't reproduce the issue. When I add 2000 MenuFlyoutItems, due to the large number, the MenuFlyoutItems cannot pop up immediately, and there will be a delay of several seconds. I suggest you could wait a few seconds after clicking on the menu. If the MenuFlyoutItems are still not displayed, could you please provide the sample to help us reproduce the issue?

Comment: Here is repo showing the issue: https://github.com/heckmouse/MenuItemIssue

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT Thank you for taking a look. Perhaps this is Windows 10 behavior and you're on Windows 11? It doesn't take much to get this behavior to occur. Here is a video in a fresh project: https://youtu.be/ewN_c8NqrZo

Comment: It seems an issue on win10. I suggest you could post the issue to [Github Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues) for better help.